# How to change form field names using JQuery plugin CloneYa

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cloneya

I know this is a very elementary question, but I am on a tight time crunch to get this project done. I am using the JQuery plugin CloneYa and after you clone the form fields I want to be able to change the form names by appending the clone count.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery CloneYa demo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">



    </head>
    <body>


            <h2>Simple Cloning</h2>
            <form class="form" method="get" action="panel_test_simple.html"> 



         <div id="animate-clone">

                <div class="toclone">
                    <p> 
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="sname" /> 
                        <label for="name">Name</label> 
                    </p> 

                    <p> 
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="semail" /> 
                        <label for="email">E-mail</label> 
                    </p> 

                    <p > 
                        <input type="text" name="web" id="sweb" /> 
                        <label for="web">Website</label> 
                    </p>  
                    <a href="#" class="clone">clone</a>
                    <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
                </div>

         </div>

                <p class="submit"> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
                </p> 

            </form>




     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-cloneya.js"></script>


      <script>

              $('#animate-clone').cloneya({


                       limit       : 5,  
                        valueClone      : false,
                        dataClone       : true,
                        deepClone       : true,  
                        clonePosition   : 'after',
                        serializeID     : true, 
                        defaultRender   : false,
                        preserveChildCount: true 

              })
                    .on('after_clone.cloneya', function (event, toclone, newclone) {
                       // alert(toclone.attr('id'));
                    });

  </script>




    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you diffine field name as array. Cloneya will automatically increment array index.

Comment: Could you send me an example. Thanks

Comment: Here is the [example](https://github.com/yapapaya/jquery-cloneya/issues/44). but based on [this discussion](https://github.com/yapapaya/jquery-cloneya/issues/42), this option may be removed in feature release.